# How to reduce hdfs replication factor on IBM Analytics Engine?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

How can I reduce the data replication factor on HDFS using IAE?

The idea is to use all the available HDFS disk space for testing purposes.

I have seen quite a few questions asking how to do this on other vendor’s Hadoop clusters but not on IBM Analytics Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ambari you would do something like the following:

1. Connect to the Ambari web URL.
2. Click on the HDFS tab on the left.
3. Click on the config tab.
4. Click on "Advanced" settings
5. Under "General," change the value of "Block Replication"
6. Now, restart the HDFS services.